# How to draw a pie-chart in Zul using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, zk, zul

As I am new to ZK framework and trying to implement javascript code inside zul.

My code is below :

```
<zk>
 <window id="HomePage" border="none" width="100%" height="100%" 
             hflex="min" style="background-color:green">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Automation',     11],
      ['Manual',      2],
      ['Report',  2],
      ['Payroll', 2],
      ['MISC',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Work Activities',
      is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

When I am executing the above code I am getting a blank page. Can anyone please suggest me how I can modify this code to get a pie-chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lacking an element to draw the chart to:
`document.getElementById('piechart_3d')` does not find anything.
So you have to add it:

```
<zk xmlns:n="native">
   <window>
    ...
   <n:div id="piechart_3d"></n:div>
```

Here I used the native namespace of ZK to cause it to render an exact HTML-`div` instead of a zk widget. This then can be resolved by `document.getElementById`.

Another hint: `hflex='min'` of the `window` produced some issues with my tests, so I removed it in the working example below.

Working example:
http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3env602/1-google-pi-chart

**UPDATE:**
Another option would be to use ZK's javascript classes to find the element to draw to. This eliminates the use of the native namespace.
`zk.Widget.$("$piechart_3d")` get's you the zk [Widget](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/7.0.3/jsdoc/zk/Widget.html), on which you can call the `$n()` function to get the DOMElement it is bound to.

```
<zk>
   <window>
       ...
       <script>
          ...
          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(zk.Widget.$("$piechart_3d").$n());
          chart.draw(data, options);  
       </script>

       <div id="piechart_3d"></div>
   </window>
</zk>
```

Example:
http://zkfiddle.org/sample/gnt3cl/3-google-pi-chart-zk

Comment: Thank you flo for your explanation and examples. Its working for me now.